# Django - Get raw request path

Tags: django

How do I get the raw request path (everything after the host name and the port) in Django?

I tried [`request.get_full_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path), but it doesn’t work for some URLs.

For example, when the URL is `http://localhost:8000/data/?`, the result is `/data/` instead of `/data/?`.

I know that the server receives the full string because it show `"GET /data/? HTTP/1.1" 200 642` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting access to the raw URL depends on your setup. I'm not aware of a way to do this with Django's development server.

[`HTTPRequest.META` is described as follows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META):

> A dictionary containing all available HTTP headers. **Available headers depend on the client and server**, but here are some examples:

If you're running `gunicorn`, `request.META["RAW_URI"]` might give you what you need.

Comment: Have you any information about IIS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `request.build_absolute_uri()`

Depends on source code:

> Builds an absolute URI from the location and the variables available in
>           this request. If no `location` is specified, the absolute URI is
>           built on `request.get_full_path()`. Anyway, if the location is
>           absolute, it is simply converted to an RFC 3987 compliant URI and
>           returned and if location is relative or is scheme-relative (i.e.,
>           `//example.com/`), it is urljoined to a base URL constructed from the
>           request variables.

Comment: Unfortunately, [`request.build_absolute_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) internally calls [`request.get_full_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path). Here is the [source code for reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/http/request/#HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri). What I would like to have is the **raw** path or even the **raw** URI (as you suggested), since they're derivable from each other.

Comment: Which urls can't you get data?

Comment: There is an example of case that does not work in the original question : `http://localhost:8000/data/?`

Comment: Ok, I tried it. I think only ? mark doesn't shown. When I add some text near ? mark, it returns with get_full_path() and build_absolute_uri() methods.